# Filter out null and empty values from JSON array in react

Tags: reactjs

How can I add an if statement or filter out null and empty values in my code?
I need to remove/ not show the name value that is null or empty.

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://url')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            data.sort(function (y,x){
                return y.listId - x.listId;
          })
          data.sort();
          this.setState({ items: data })
          console.log(this.state.items)
     })
     .catch(console.table)
  }

  return (
      <div className="list-container">
          <h1>My List</h1>
          {this.state.items.map((item) => (
              <div className="list">
          )}
```

Here's an example of my json array:

```
[
    {"id": 755, "listId": 2, "name": ""},
    {"id": 203, "listId": 2, "name": ""},
    {"id": 684, "listId": 1, "name": "Item 684"},
    {"id": 276, "listId": 1, "name": "Item 276"},
    {"id": 736, "listId": 3, "name": null},
    {"id": 926, "listId": 4, "name": null}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [filter array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in this way:

`data.filter(d => d !== "" && d !== null)`

Add this line before the sorting function like this:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://url')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      const filteredData = data.filter(d => d !== "" && d !== null)
      filteredData.sort(function (y,x){
        return y.listId - x.listId;
      })
      filteredData.sort();
      this.setState({ items: filteredData })
      console.log(this.state.items)
    })
    .catch(console.table)
}
```

Also (probably unrelated), why are you sorting two times?

Answer (score 0):

You can [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array by doing this:

```js
const items = this.state.items.filter(item => item.name !== '' && item.name !== null);
```

This will return a new array that doesn't have items with a blank or null name.

Edit for comment:

You can add this in your code like this:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://url')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      const filteredData = data.filter(item => item.name !== '' && item.name !== null);
      filteredData.sort(function (y,x){
        return y.listId - x.listId;
      })
      filteredData.sort();
      this.setState({ items: filteredData })
      console.log(this.state.items)
    })
    .catch(console.table)
}
```

Comment: Where in my code can I add the suggested line of code?

Comment: You can add that before setting the state like @christos stated in their answer. I will edit my answer

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I tried the suggested code and it gives me back an empty array @pbrune

Comment: Sorry about that. I was using this.state.items instead of data. I have updated the code snippet in my original answer. Let me know if that works for you

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = [
{"id": 755, "listId": 2, "name": ""},
{"id": 203, "listId": 2, "name": ""},
{"id": 684, "listId": 1, "name": "Item 684"},
{"id": 276, "listId": 1, "name": "Item 276"},
{"id": 736, "listId": 3, "name": null},
{"id": 926, "listId": 4, "name": null}] 

console.log(data.filter(({name}) => name))
```